# Are start parameter reused from /etc/init.d/XY restart?

Tags: init

I start my postgreSQL-Db with this command:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_ctl
    -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
    -l /var/log/globus/postgresql.log -o -i start
```

are the parameters kept if I restart the sql server with

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I don't know" but I doubt it.

You should read `/etc/init.d/postgresql` to see what it actually does.

I'm not sure on the 'best practice' but I would assume that most options you can give on the command line can be set in postgresql's configuration file instead.

**If you are able to specify those options in the configuration file, I would strongly suggest you do so**, rather than modifying `/etc/init.d/postgresql`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will check the file and the configuration possibilities...